# Agrupamento de objetos de um array por datas equivalentes

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom dia,
estou com uma dúvida onde tenho um array de objetos da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
var producao = [{data: '2019-12-19', producao_ok: 10, producao_nok: 20}, {data: '2018-10-01', producao_ok: 5, producao_nok: 1}, {data: '2019-12-19', producao_ok: 100, producao_nok: 2}, {data: '2018-10-01', producao_ok: 100, producao_nok: 10}, {data: '2019-12-19', producao_ok: 10, producao_nok: 20}];
```

Existe alguma forma de, por exemplo com o reduce, fazer o somatorio dos valores de producao_ok e producao_nok por agrupamento de datas, tendo em mente que não  tenho ideia das datas iniciais e finais do objeto?

exemplo de resultado esperado após inserir em um array novo:

```
var objetoNovo = [{data: '2019-12-19', producao_ok: 120, producao_nok: 42}, {data: '2018-10-01', producao_ok: 105, producao_nok: 11}];
```

Comment: Já considerou usar uma estrutura de dados chave/valor, por exemplo um map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adaptando a resposta da pergunta [**"how to group by and sum array of object?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364431/3388148) para o seu exemplo, podemos utilizar a função `reduce` do `array` para obter um objeto com chaves de acordo com o campo que você que agrupar e somando os demais valores. Depois disso é possível utilizar a função `Object.values` para obter os valores selecionados previamente.

```js
const producao = [{
  data: '2019-12-19',
  producao_ok: 10,
  producao_nok: 20
}, {
  data: '2018-10-01',
  producao_ok: 5,
  producao_nok: 1
}, {
  data: '2019-12-19',
  producao_ok: 100,
  producao_nok: 2
}, {
  data: '2018-10-01',
  producao_ok: 100,
  producao_nok: 10
}, {
  data: '2019-12-19',
  producao_ok: 10,
  producao_nok: 20
}];

const reduzir = (acumulador, { data, producao_ok, producao_nok }) => {
  // Se ainda não existir o registro no agrupamento
  if (!acumulador[data]) {
    acumulador[data] = {
      data,
      producao_ok: producao_ok,
      producao_nok: producao_nok,
    };
  } else {
    acumulador[data].producao_ok += producao_ok;
    acumulador[data].producao_nok += producao_nok;
  }

  return acumulador;
};

const agrupar = (conjunto) => {
  return Object.values(conjunto.reduce(reduzir, {}));
};

console.log(agrupar(producao));
```

---

> [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
>
> O método `Object.values()` retorna um array com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto, na mesma ordem provida pelo [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) laço (sendo a diferença que o laço for-in também enumera as propriedades na cadeia protótipos).

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso! Valeu demais!