# Group array com javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Tenho uma aplicação backend em node que retorna o seguinte array:

```
let res= [
           {
                codigo: '0341',
                codigo_1: '0320',
                visao: '14',
                total: 24,
                data: '201502'
            },
            {
                codigo:'0341',
                codigo_1:'0320',
                visao:'14',
                total:25,
                data: '201504'
            },
            {
                codigo:'0321',
                codigo_1:'0320',
                visao:'14',
                total:31,
                data: '201506'
            },
            {
                codigo:'0341',
                codigo_1:'0320',
                visao:'14',
                total:55,
                data: '201502'
            },
        ]
```

**O atributo data é composto por ano/mês, não consigo alterar pois vem da base dessa forma**

Preciso do retorno agrupado inicialmente por data e depois por código somando os totais, tendo o seguinte retorno:

```
 [
      {
          data: '201502'
          codigo: '0341'
          total: 79
      },
      {
          data: '201506'
          codigo: '0321'
          total: 31
      },
      {
          data: '201504'
          codigo: '0320'
          total: 25
      }
  ]
```

Já tentei alguma formas, mas sem sucesso. Segue:

```
const resultadosAgrupados = res.reduce(function (valorAcumulador, valorArray) {
            if (!valorAcumulador[valorArray.data]) {
                valorAcumulador[valorArray.data] = { ...valorArray };
                return valorAcumulador;
            }
            valorAcumulador[valorArray.data].total += valorArray.total;
            return valorAcumulador
        }, [])
```

E também usando o uniqBy:

```
let teste = _.uniqBy(res, 'data')
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptando [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/430243/59479) resposta da pergunta [**Agrupamento de objetos de um array por datas equivalentes**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430239/agrupamento-de-objetos-de-um-array-por-datas-equivalentes) para sua necessidade temos as seguintes funções:

```js
let dados = [{
    codigo: '0341',
    codigo_1: '0320',
    visao: '14',
    total: 24,
    data: '201502'
  },
  {
    codigo: '0341',
    codigo_1: '0320',
    visao: '14',
    total: 25,
    data: '201504'
  },
  {
    codigo: '0321',
    codigo_1: '0320',
    visao: '14',
    total: 31,
    data: '201506'
  },
  {
    codigo: '0341',
    codigo_1: '0320',
    visao: '14',
    total: 55,
    data: '201502'
  },
];

const reduzir = (acumulador, { data, codigo_1, total }) => {
  // Se ainda não existir o registro no agrupamento
  if (!acumulador[data]) {
    acumulador[data] = {
      data,
      codigo: codigo_1,
      total: total,
    };
  } else {
    acumulador[data].total += total;
  }

  return acumulador;
};

const agrupar = (conjunto) => {
  return Object.values(conjunto.reduce(reduzir, {}));
};

console.log(agrupar(dados));
```

---

> [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
>
> O método `Object.values()` retorna um array com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto, na mesma ordem provida pelo `for...in` laço (sendo a diferença que o laço for-in também enumera as propriedades na cadeia protótipos).

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```